# Keeping AgiCahnnel alive for a long time

Tags: asterisk, agi

Following question is related to asterisk-java API.

In our application we want to be able to send commands to a specific asterisk channel during a long period of time.

It's a long-lasting call that we want to manipulate (may last for few hours).

One of ways of approaching it was to make an `AGI` call from asterisk which will create an `AgiScript` that will hold an `AgiChannel` instance that we'll use to send our commands.

I know that the channel is closed once `AgiScript#serve()` method is finished.

As a workaround we pause the `serve()` thread to keep `AgiChannel` open as long as we need.

**Questions**

Should we look out for any timeouts that will eventually close the channel automatically?

Do we need to send at least `NoOp` periodically to keep it open?

Overall this doesn't look like a good solution anyway  so I want to ask if we have any other options to achieve our goal?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, you may be better off using the AMI (asterisk manager interface).

If your call is bridged (talking to someone) then you don't really have control. In the AGI you would have told it to call Dial, and that thread would be blocked until Dial returns, so there's not really a way for that thread to send new commands. Even if AsteriskJava wasn't blocked, asterisk itself wouldn't be expecting a new command.

From the AMI you can use the Redirect action to work around this problem and redirect the channel away from the bridge. Or if you just need to e.g. get some channel variables, you can do that asynchronously from the AMI.

It's even possible to issue AGI commands over the AMI.

[Here](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API)'s a list of some AMI commands. You can see all of them from inside asterisk with "manager show commands".

You could use ORIGINATE to create a call, and then ChannelRedirect to redirect it to various extensions in the dialplan.

If you Originate or ChannelRedirect the call to the AGI application in async mode, then you can use the AMI command "AGI" to issue it AGI commands over the AMI.

Comment: Can you please clarify the AMI part:
Let's say we sent an Originate action through AMI. Call gets connected. Can we send some other action to put this channel into a MeetMe conf or play some sound file to him? Can we execute some arbitrary asterisk application against this channel via AMI (or any other means)?

Comment: Using redirect for dialplan control is EXTREAMLY bad practice becuase every redirect do mangle channel.

Comment: Redirect isn't any worse than an attended transfer.  If you need to break out of an application (like Dial) while in progress, it's about your only options.

Comment: EVERY redirect rename channel,creating new structure and copiing to that new one. That process called "channel mangle"

Comment: I've never heard it called a "channel mangle" before. The source code refers to it as a channel "masquerade". It's used in a variety of situations, including transfers and local channel optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You should start new thread using default threads class and move to it proccessing after hangup.

Answer (score 0):

You can control all interactions with async agi, it is fully asynchronous and you can interact with the calls as you need. You have events returned to you for everything, starting with that in mind you can model objects for your use case and implementat any behaviour you could have with standard agi + you also get the AMI power.